# Get specific metadata from a group of open databases

Tags: metadata

**Use case:**
I am investigating common characteristics of chosen databases. By databases I understand collections of data, possibly with relations between them.

I want to collect metadata for all databases that I could possibly find that meet some criteria. That accounts for two steps:

1. Getting a set of databases available publicly
2. Getting metadata that describe these databases e.g.

   - number of datasets/tables/collections
   - size of these datasets (filesystem, number of records)
   - etc.

**Question:**
Is it possible to find such data? I could possibly write a script that fetches that information if it is hard to access manually but is it actually possible to find?

Comment: What if I collected these information myself? E.g. downloaded datasets and then measured specific values? But then what source should I use to find relational-like datasets?